# Python: Simulate data correlated with a given array

Tags: correlation, python, simulation

Although there are some existing methods (e.g. `np.random.multivariate_normal`) for simulating random correlated variables for given mean, corr and assumed distribution, I couldn't find a way to simulate data which is postive/negative correlated with the given array.

More specifically, for given a gene expression matrix, I'd like to simulate some other fake genes which are highly positive/negative correlated with a specific gene.

What I did was to order it first and add a random noise (which fits normal distribution).

```
expr_Asc = pd.DataFrame(expr.sort_values(ascending = True))
expr_Dsc = pd.DataFrame(expr.sort_values(ascending = False))
expr_Pos = ex_matrix.loc[:, expr_Asc.index]

Pos_Corr = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc = 20, scale = 5, size = (434,50)), 
                            columns = ['Posgene' + str(i) for i in range(50)],
                            index = expr_Asc.index)
Neg_Corr = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc = 5, scale = 2, size = (434,50)), 
                            columns = ['Neggene' + str(i) for i in range(50)],
                            index = expr_Asc.index)
```

Consequently, it gives relatively high linear correlation.

Any ideas for stimulating non-linear correlated dataset? Thanks. :D

Comment: bootstrapping.  bootstrap resampling of a curated array.

Comment: `np.random.multivariable_normal` has a `cov` argument that let's you specify the covariance (correlation) structure.  Not sure what you mean by non-linear correlation, since correlation measures linear relationships